# Macbook not restarting/rebooting after completing a "successful" installation of Catalina OS

Tags: catalina

I have tried installing Catalina OS 3 times now. The installation completes and when I click restart for the OS to take affect it closes all applications and doesn't restart. I tried restarting the computer myself, but it doesn't take affect. After trying multiple times installing it again and again - I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: What model of Mac is this? Have you tried holding down Alt at boot, to select the startup disk? Have you tried resetting the NVRAM?

Comment: What do you mean “doesn’t restart.”  Does it just sit there at the completion screen, or does it POST, look like it’s going to boot and does nothing.  Do you get an Apple logo, flashing question mark, a stop sign, etc?  How do you “restart the system yourself”?